# Getting ClassCast Exception, after changing layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout for an activity xml

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I changed the Activity Layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout but end up with following error:-

09-18 16:18:07.949: E/AndroidRuntime(635): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams

Everything is working fine in LinearLayout also, except align_parentBottom property for last EditText. which should be in bottom.

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/3, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        selectOne.setLayoutParams(params);
        selectTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
        selectThree.setLayoutParams(params);
```

selectOne, selectTwo and Three are buttons at top of the page. I am getting error on this line only.

my activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_violet"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/emptyText1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/selectReleased"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/not_selected_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Released"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/selectReleasing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/selected_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This Weekend"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/selectUpcoming"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/not_selected_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Upcoming"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5px" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/monthLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/emptyText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emptyText1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/select_month"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/emptyText2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5px" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/msgTxt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/selectAfterLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emptyText2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/selectAfterLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/aboveLay"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/moviesLV"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.0" >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textTest111"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Got the following error:-

```
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:654)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:306)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-18 17:47:52.869: E/AndroidRuntime(1122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your xml and source code.

Comment: Its very long xml and sourcecode Rajesh. But what I come up with the error in following line of code DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

  LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/3, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  selectOne.setLayoutParams(params);
  selectTwo.setLayoutParams(params);
  selectThree.setLayoutParams(params);   selectOne, selectTwo and Three are buttons at top of activity.

Comment: without the xml its hard to debug. do you set the parameters of the layout programatically?

Comment: if you do it programatically, just post the few lines that are concerned with this problem.

Comment: use http://pastebin.com/ paste your code.

Comment: Hi Gan/Rajesh, I have posted the code where getting the problem in main Question. Please help.

Comment: if my solution has worked, please accept the answer as it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

When you were first using `LinearLayout` and used `LayoutParams`, your IDE likely imported `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` automatically since that was the one you were using. Now that you've switched to a `RelativeLayout`, you need to be using `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`. You can either:

1. Change your import statement to `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` vs `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`
2. Change your `LayoutParams` line to be more specific: `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the parameters to relative layout.
Try something like this
`LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.widthPixels/3, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

Comment: could you tell me what selectOne and the rest are. it was my assumption that they were relative layouts.

Comment: got to be `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` since the error happens in `LinearLayout.measureHorizontal()`. LayoutParams of a view must be of the type of the parent view.

Comment: @Gan Log is posted in main Q. Also selectOne, Two and Three are buttons for selectReleased, selectReleasing and selectUpcoming. Please see the xml posted in main Q.